# How to install GTK3 on Amazon Linux?

Tags: firefox, selenium, gtk

I cannot install Firefox on my amazon linux machine. All articles I can google tells about [GTK2](https://joekiller.com/2012/06/03/install-firefox-on-amazon-linux-x86_64-compiling-gtk/#comment-6035) but how can I Install GTK3? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I know it doesn't answer your question, but I found it easier (much easier) to install Chrome instead.

If this is a valid alternative for you, [this article](https://intoli.com/blog/installing-google-chrome-on-centos/) gives a script that does everything.